# I tried it a lot and I want to get occurrence of 4 without using count function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried it a lot and I want to get occurrence of 4 without using count function

```
n = int(input())            #number of input
for i in range(n):            #range
    l = []                     #list
    x = int(input())          #input 
    while (x > 0):            #innserting input into list
        y = x % 10              
        x = x / 10
        l.append(y)
    z = 0
    for i in l:
        if (i == 4):         # calculating no of occurrence
            z = z + 1          
    print(z)
```

Comment: Show a program run with input and output and the expected output as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code on stack overflow. Do you have a question about it?

Comment: There's a syntax error in this line: `y = x % 10              into list`

Comment: put `z = 0` outside the loop. it change to 0 every time run the loop. so you can not get occurrence of 4.

Comment: You probably meant `x = x // 10` (note the integer division), otherwise `x` will turn into a float and never be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler way of solving it.

```
number = int(input("Enter Number: "))
fours = [] #create list to store all the fours

for x in str(number): #loop through the number as a string
    if x == '4': #check if the character if 4
        fours.append(x) #add it to the list of fours
    
print("Number of fours: " + str(len(fours))) #prints the length of the array
```